# сохранение картинок, имея только url

Tags: парсер, img

у меня такой вопрос, можно ли как-то имея только url картинки(6000 ссылок), сохранить ее к себе на сервер, чтобы создавался такой же путь к картинке, как и у источника где мы ее взяли

Comment: а в чем вы видите проблему? и средствами какого языка вы хотите это решить, или еще какими средствами

Comment: `wget -x -i <имя файла с картинками> ` и чуточку подождать. Если ничего не случится, то на диске будет сохранена структура каталогов и дальше нужно будет только натравить apache/nging и готово.